# Connect to VM on Fiware Lab: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh, connection-timeout, fiware, filab

In [FIWARE Lab](https://cloud.lab.fiware.org/), I create a VM instance, keypair, etc as in [the tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/flopezaguilar/setting-up-your-virtual-infrastructure-using-fi-lab-cloud-32388357):

[image: vm]

Add port 22 to the security group rules:

[image: security group rules]

I follow the instructions to connect to ssh:

```
Open the Terminal
Locate the keypair asocciate to this Instance when launching it.
my_keypair.pem

Modify the keypair permissions in order to make it not publicly viewable.
chmod 400 my_keypair.pem

Connect to the Instance using its public IP.
ssh -i my_keypair.pem root@10.0.136.107
```

yet:

```
$ ssh -i nother-keypair.pem root@10.0.136.107
ssh: connect to host 10.0.136.107 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Why does this happen? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to associate a public IP to the VM instance.
to do that:
compute->security->floating ip address->Allocate ip to project -> allocate ip-> associate ip->chose the instance-> associate.
now you will be able to use ssh with your public ip address

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to configure the network inside fi-ware cloud website.
Then you should be able to assign a floating IP to the instance you are trying to connect. This will give you a public IP so you can access the VM from anywhere. The IP you wrote here is a local IP.
If you were able to assign a floating IP do this:

```
ssh -i yourKey.pem root@floatingIP
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the IP address that you are using (10.0.136.107) in a private one, you cannot access to that network from outside of the infrastructure.

If you want to access to any VM using SSH, you need to associate a public IP to the VM instance.